# MongoDB: query array within embedded document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following doc definition (it's ruby)

```
class Block
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :index, type: Integer  # index 0,1,..  
  field :codes, type: Array    #[A, B, C,... ]

  embedded_in :Video
end

class Video
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :blocks, :order => :index.asc
end
```

I want to query matching the property `video.blocks.codes`, but it is an array property of an embedded doc. I mainly want to do two types of queries:

- How many blocks exist with a non-null/non-empty `codes` array?
- How many blocks exist where the codes array matches a certain string in a given position?

Here's an example of the data I'm trying to match:

```
video#1
blocks: [{index: 1, codes:["a","g","c"]}, {index: 2, codes: [] }]

video#2
blocks: [{index: 1, codes:["x","b","d", "e"]}, {index: 2, codes: ["x","b"] }]
```

For example, I want to know *how many blocks are there without non-empty codes array* (answer is **three blocks**), and *how many blocks are there with a `b` in the second position(index 1)* (answer is there are **two**).

I'm using the `mongoid` driver so ideally the query would use the driver, but plain mongo is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is dot notation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation

Question 1:

> - How many blocks exist with a non-null/non-empty codes array?

```
db.videos.find( { 'video.blocks.codes.0' : { $exists : true } } )
```

Effectively does the zero-th element of the array exist.  For speed you create an index on `video.blocks.codes`. Also note that you will get back all of the video documents with at least 1 non-empty codes array within a block.  To count the blocks you will have to do client side processing to remove the extra blocks.

Question 2:

> - How many blocks exist where the codes array matches a certain string in a given position?

Very similar answer.  For a position 3:

```
db.videos.find( { 'video.blocks.codes.3' : 'the magic code' } )
```

Sorry I don't know Mongoid but hopefully you can translate the above.

HTH - 
Rob.

Edit:

> This doesn't work, because blocks is embedded and codes is an array within blocks.

I don't think I understand the question then.  The shell returns What I expect.

Example from the shell (reformatted) - First the data:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7cfff0ccc6eb8b11c82b1"), 
  "blocks" : [    
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [  "a", "g", "c" ] },
     { "index" : 2, "codes" : [ ] } 
  ] 
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7d0300ccc6eb8b11c82b2"), 
  "blocks" : [
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [ "x", "b", "d", "e" ] },        
     { "index" : 2, "codes" : [ "x", "b" ] } 
  ] 
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7d0a50ccc6eb8b11c82b3"), 
  "blocks" : [ 
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [ ] } 
  ] 
}
```

First Query: Find all documents with a block with at least 1 code:

```
> db.test.find( { 'blocks.codes.0' : { $exists : true } } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7cfff0ccc6eb8b11c82b1"), 
  "blocks" : [
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [ "a", "g", "c" ] },
     { "index" : 2, "codes" : [ ] } 
   ] 
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7d0300ccc6eb8b11c82b2"), 
  "blocks" : [ 
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [ "x", "b", "d", "e" ] },
     { "index" : 2, "codes" : [ "x", "b" ] } 
   ] 
}
```

Second Query: Find all documents where the n'th code is a specific value. In this case I chose the second (index 1) is 'g'.

```
> db.test.find( { 'blocks.codes.1' : "g" } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b7cfff0ccc6eb8b11c82b1"), 
  "blocks" : [ 
     { "index" : 1, "codes" : [ "a", "g", "c" ] },
     { "index" : 2, "codes" : [ ] } 
  ] 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because `blocks` is embedded and `codes` is an array within `blocks`.

Comment: I updated to show the queries working as I expected from the shell.  Can you update the question with what you expect the results of the queries to be?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO `Block` should be a separate collection with an additional attribute `num_codes` (and not embedded, code untested).

```
class Video
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :blocks
end

class Block
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :video
    field :index
    field :num_codes
    field :codes

    # warning pseudo code ahead:
    before_save :update_codes
    def update_codes
       # set num_codes to length of codes
       # delete all codes belonging to this block and recreate them
    end
end
```

To query for empty blocks: `Blocks.where(num_codes : 0)`. This solves requirement 1.

Regarding requirement 2: As far as I know, MongoDB does not allow you to query for values at a specific index within an array (altough I might be wrong on this one). Again my suggestion would be to make a separate collection (code untested):

```
class Code
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :block
   field :position
   field :value
end

Code.where(position : 3, value : 'x')
```

Saving a video will thus take about 2-n insertions depending on the size of `codes`. But the collections are indexable (`[:num_codes]` for `Blocks` and `[:position, :value]` for `Code`) and should give you reasonable query performance - even for large collections. Hope that helps.

Comment: I know I should have it in a separate collection, but I don't; I can't really change the schema right now. That's why I'm asking SO :). But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you unable to change the way you store things in MongoDB or only the schema of your input data? (or both?)

Comment: Well, then you're somewhat out of luck, I guess. :)